# I can't load vue dynamic component from ajax results

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am learning vue with a symfony project and I have a problem.

I'm trying to load a dynamic component with results from an ajax call for scrolling pagination, but can't get it to work.

This is my code:

Gamecard.vue

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'gamecard',
    props: ['name', 'description', 'tourneyscount'],
    data() {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

game-card.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Gamecard from './../../components/Gamecard'

new Vue({
    el: '#game-card',
    components: {
        Gamecard,
        'gamecard': () => import('./../../components/Gamecard')
    }
})
```

in this case, Gamecard is for initial components and 'gamecard': () ... is for dynamic components

game-cards-container.html.twig  this have a loop for charge cards

```
{% for game in games %}
    {% include 'partials/cards/game-card.html.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

game-card.html.twig

```
<gamecard
    name="{{ game.getName() }}"
    description="{{ game.getDescription() }}"
    tourneyscount="{{ (game.getTourneys() | length > 0) ? game.getTourneys() | length : '0' }} {{ 'active tourneys' }}"
></gamecard>
```

my controller responses

```
 if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                [
                    'code' => Response::HTTP_OK,
                    'cards' => $this->render('partials/containers/game-cards-container.html.twig', [
                        'async' => true,
                        'games' => $gameList
                    ])->getContent()
                ]
            );
        }

        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'games' => $gameList
        ]);
```

and the ajax call:

```
const url = window.location.hostname + '/' + page;

    fetch('?page=' + page, {
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.code === 200) {
                console.log(response.cards);
                document.getElementById('game-card').innerHTML += response.cards
                canLoad = true;
            } else {
                canLoad = false;
            }
        });
```

anybody can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. It may not be optimal, but it works.

I have seen that vue does not render new components added by ajax after being mounted, so the solution I thought was to create the component again after the ajax request

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Gamecard from './../../components/Gamecard'

function createGameCards() {
     new Vue({
        el: '#game-card',
        components: {
            Gamecard
        },
    });
}

createGameCards();

export {createGameCards}
```

and this in my ajax request

```
fetch('?page=' + page, {
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.code === 200) {
                document.getElementById('game-card').innerHTML += response.cards.trim();
                createGameCards();
                canLoad = true;
            } else {
                canLoad = false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).